# Issue with selectors and conditionals in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple HTML template that's used multiple times across the document. It's essentially the following `div` element wrapping around several `p` elements and another `div` element with the class `button`. For visualization purposes, here's an example:

```
<div class="content">    
    <p>First paragraph</p>
    <p>Second paragraph</p>

    <div><a class="button" href="http://www.apple.com/ipad/">Change me jQuery!</a></div>
</div>

<div class="content">    
    <p>First paragraph</p>
    <p>Second paragraph</p>

    <div><a class="button" href="http://www.apple.com/iphone/">Change me jQuery!</a></div>
</div>
```

Now, the users who will use this template to publish content on the site not always will use the same exact url in that anchor tag, but I do know exactly which ones they can use. So what I'm trying to do with my code is the following:

1. Once the content has been published and the anchor tag given a url
   address, I want to check that address and see if there's a specific
   word in it. If that word is found, then change the anchor text to something of my choice.
2. Do the same again but this time checking for a different word in the url string.

Here's what I've written:

```
$('.content').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $findP = $this.find('p');

    if ($findP.length > 2) {
        // Run some code
    } else if ( ($findP.length <= 2) && ($('a[href*="ipad"]')) ) {
        $this.find('a.button').text('Visit iPad site');
    } else if ( ($findP.length <= 2) && ($('a[href*="iphone"]')) ) {
        $this.find('a.button').text('Visit iPhone site');
    }
});​
```

**Issues:**

- Both anchor tags' text *only* change to the string of text that I've written in the first **else if** statement inside the `.text()` jQuery method. In my example here, the first anchor tag should take the text "Visit iPad site" while the second one should be "Visit iPhone site". Here's a working fiddle of this example: http://jsfiddle.net/vj4xZ/1/

I'm guessing the issue is here that once the first element is found, all anchor tags are assigned what's in the .text() method and the code stops right there without looking for the what's in the second **else if** statement. If that's the case, or the issue at hand is something else, then how can I get that to working properly? Any help with this will be appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/vj4xZ/2/

You need to change your conditions to this:

```
} else if ( ($findP.length <= 2) && ($this.find('a[href*="ipad"]').length) ) {
```

`$('a[href*="ipad"]')` - means - if there is an anchor with `ipad` in href *somewhere in the document*

What I changed - is limited searching the anchor only by current element with `$this.find()`

You may also use `$('a[href*="ipad"]', $this)` instead, it would do the same work

Comment: Hiya @zerkms howz it bruv, can you please see my answer below it suffice the needs of what OP asked "+1 I thought of the same thing before hand" Cheers man!

Comment: Seconds after I posted the question I thought about the problem that you highlighted with my conditions, and I'm glad you've solved it. Thanks a lot! I've also tried the second option you mentioned but I can't get it to work unfortunately.

Comment: @zerkms: got you. Thanks one more time.

Answer (score 1):

Hiya made a lil different **demo here:** http://jsfiddle.net/bKJfq/15/

Above demo uses one of this selector: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

once the selector matches it will change the text to the desired text you want.

This can very well be less verbose way; Please let me know if I missed anything.

Hope this helps B-)

**code**

```
   $('a[href*="ipad"]').text("Visit iPad site");
   $('a[href*="iphone"]').text("Visit iPhone site");
```

Comment: Yeah you got this right, and it's indeed less verbose coding. Thank you!